# Is there any way to find boot up time of any windows Application?

Tags: python, windows, automation, operating-system

Suppose I am using VLC Player and I want to calculate the time it takes to boot using python , is there any way?

I have tried winium automation , but elements load too slowly. I want to get boot up time of my application and it boots in 4-5 seconds , whereas winium usually takes more than that to find the location of element.

If anyone can suggest any better way via backend automation, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you need to find time from moment you executed the app to the moment the window appears. You can do that with pygetwindow library. Here's the code:

```python
    import pygetwindow as pw
    import time
    # here's code that executing the program, but i just put comment
    start = time.time()
    while 1: # waiting until window appears
        # getWindowsWithTitle method returns empty list if it didn't found any windows with this name
        if pw.getWindowsWithTitle('VLC'): #if it founds the window, loop will break
            break
    stop = time.time()
    result = stop - start # result is time in seconds (type float)
```

EDIT

You also can detect start of application by checking if amount of windows changed.

```py
    import pygetwindow as pw
    import time
    starting_amount = len(pw.getAllWindows()) # amount of windows
    # here's code that executing the program, but i just put comment
    start = time.time()
    while 1: # waiting until window appears
        if len(pw.getAllWindows()) > starting_amount: #if amount of windows is bigger than it was before we executed the program
            break
    stop = time.time()
    result = stop - start # result is time in seconds (type float)
```

This should work with LD Player

Comment: Thanks , but can we do that for Applications such as LD Player , where progress bar keeps on coming before the application get loaded.